# Testing variable vs multiple true statements but stoping in the very first is true (If operator)

Tags: if-statement

I´m starting to develop  a piping calculation software, at some point it reads the input pressure and is supposed to return a value (pipe schedule) corresponding to the pressure value. The problem is that if require to get the "schedule" given the pressure it is likely my statement is true for all the possibilities, but I want it to stop and return the value when the very first statement is fulfilled. In the following example assume the pressure input is "60", so it is true for all the statements (167, 241 and 397) but I need it to stop when the very first is met, or continue with the following if the first one is not true:

```
diameter_= float(diameter.get())
pressure_= float(pipepressure.get())

if diameter_== 2:

    if (pressure_*1.5) < 167:
        schedule.set("40")

    if (pressure_*1.5) < 241:
        schedule.set("80")

    if (pressure_*1.5) < 397:
        schedule.set("160")
```

Comment: Hello! Tag with language, please.

Comment: Else if might be the way to go.

Comment: Got the code rith already guys, "elif" after if is the key. Thank you.